# DataTable : java.lang.ClassCastException in thingworx

Tags: thingworx

DataTable : java.lang.ClassCastException in thingworx arries internally when I am watching data through home widget of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen when you tried to change the internal structure of the table which was managed by thingworx like location, timestamp.etc.